# How did they make a fading, animated signin button?

Tags: fading

If you look at www.me.com by Apple.  Yoiu will see the SIGNIN button loops in fadein and fadeout animation. Is this jquery?

Erik

Comment: Right-click/View Source says no.

Comment: Looks like apple's proprietary javascript wrapper library. However, you can do this in jQuery.

Comment: The fading only starts when you click inside the input field.  Very clever.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure looks like javascript to me.